# Gson [java] - when parsing json string, I just want to add some characters to it

Tags: gson, deserialization

I define "Response", "Person", "Course" class :

```java
class Response {
    private int countA; // record the length of data
    private List<Person> data;

    // getter & setter
}

class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int countB; // record the length of list
    private List<Course> list;

    // getter & setter
}

class Course {
    private String name;

    // getter & setter
}
```

And I have a json string (return from some server) like this :

```java
{
   "countA":1,
   "data":
   {
      "name":"peter",
      "age":18,
      "countB":1,
      "list":
      {
         "name":"math"
      }
   }
}
```

But when the "countA" > 1 or "countB" > 1 , it will be like this :

```java
{
   "countA":2,
   "data":
   [                                // when countA > 1, it have this one '['
      {
         "name":"amy",
         "age":17,
         "countB":1,
         "list":
         {
            "name":"music"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"david",
         "age":16,
         "countB":2,
         "list":
         [                          // when countB > 1, it have this one '['
            {
               "name":"music"
            },
            {
               "name":"computer"
            }
         ]                          // when countB > 1, it have this one ']'
      }
   ]                                // when countA > 1, it have this one ']'
}
```

So, I want to customize my deserializer which just doing add two characters ' [ ' & ' ] ' to data or list when countA or countB = 1 respectively :

```java
class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List>{

    public List deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {


        String jsonString = json.toString();

        // fix json string to my expected format
        if(!(jsonString.startsWith("[") && jsonString.endsWith("]")))
            jsonString = "["+jsonString+"]";

        // get the XXX type from List<XXX>
        Type valueType = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        // call default deserializer
        return context.deserialize(new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,JsonElement.class), valueType);
    }
}
```

In my main() :

```java
String jsonStrng = ...; // return from some server
Response bean = (Response) fromJson(jsonString, Response.class); // get the following error
```

Method fromJson() :

```java
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static Object fromJson(String data, Class clazz) {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new MyDeserializer()) .create();

    Object obj = gson.fromJson(data, clazz);

    gson = null;
    return obj;
}
```

But I have the error :

```java
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

I know the reason why I get this error :

1. json string have two level List type
2. in my deserializer, finally I call the default deserializer

But instead of calling the default deserializer, if I try to call my deserializer again, it causes the infinite loop.

My question is how do I fix it ?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was that JSON designed on your own or by a third-party service and you cannot change the response format? (Please note that your deserializer has serious performance issues due to the strings v being implemented without what Gson provides).

Comment: That JSON is from a third-party service and I cannot change the response format. In addition, what does "without what Gson provides" mean ? I don't realize it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson is a great library providing a lot of functionality in efficient ways, and I think that your current approach should be discouraged for several reasons. Let's take a closer look.

```java
String jsonString = json.toString();
```

`toString()` is basically used for debugging purposes and it's use should be discouraged except classes like `StringBuilder` where `toString` is the only way to obtain the result *by design*. The result string may look like what you really want, but this result may be expensive and not always accurate (or even change in the future).

```java
if(!(jsonString.startsWith("[") && jsonString.endsWith("]")))
    jsonString = "["+jsonString+"]";
```

This is another penalty point for the performance and memory consumption: concatenating a large string will result into an even larger string whilst the first one will still consume the memory. Note that `JsonDeserializer` provides you a ready-to-use `JsonElement` that has a very convenient API to inspect JSON trees (JSON object representations in memory).

```java
Type valueType = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Possibly a `ClassCastException` here: the given type is not necessarily meant to be parameterized thus it may be not a `ParameterizedType` instance due to how generic types work in Java.

```
return context.deserialize(new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,JsonElement.class), valueType);
```

You're losing your `Gson` configuration here when creating a new `Gson` instance from scratch, thus it may work in not the way you could expect it to work. Additionally, `Gson` instantiation is relatively an expensive operation and usually does not need re-instantiation.

How it could be reworked:

```java
// Use generic types for good
final class UnwrappedElementListDeserializer<T>
        implements JsonDeserializer<List<T>> {

    // This deserializer holds no state, therefore it can be instantiated once...
    private static final JsonDeserializer<?> unwrappedElementListDeserializer = new UnwrappedElementListDeserializer<>();

    private UnwrappedElementListDeserializer() {
    }

    // But any caller won't ever know it unless the caller checks instance references equality with ==. But any reason of doing that?
    static <T> JsonDeserializer<List<T>> getUnwrappedElementListDeserializer() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        final JsonDeserializer<List<T>> castUnwrappedElementListDeserializer = (JsonDeserializer) unwrappedElementListDeserializer;
        return castUnwrappedElementListDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> deserialize(final JsonElement rootJsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // Gson uses JsonNull to denote the JSON null value -- it has API, whilst Java null can never have its "API"...
        if ( rootJsonElement.isJsonNull() ) {
            // Empty lists are better than null
            // Note that Collections.emptyList() might be an option too, but Gson uses mutable lists (you can modify them), so we do either
            // emptyList() cannot be modified, so we just return a new modifiable list
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        // Is it just an object? It looks like a single element out of an array
        final Type elementType = tryGetTypeParameter0(type);
        if ( rootJsonElement.isJsonObject() ) {
            final T element = context.deserialize(rootJsonElement, elementType);
            // Collections.singletonList() is immutable too
            final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(element);
            return list;
        }
        // If it's an array, then it must have two or more elements
        if ( rootJsonElement.isJsonArray() ) {
            // context.deserialize(jsonElement, type) cannot work due to infinite self-recursion
            final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( final JsonElement jsonElement : rootJsonElement.getAsJsonArray() ) {
                final T element = context.deserialize(jsonElement, elementType);
                list.add(element);
            }
            return list;
        }
        throw new JsonParseException("Cannot parse: " + rootJsonElement);
    }

    private static Type tryGetTypeParameter0(final Type type) {
        if ( type instanceof ParameterizedType ) {
            final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
            return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
        return Object.class;
    }

}
```

The data-transfer objects:

```java
final class Response {

    // Gson can assign final fields
    // Primitive types like `int` cannot be `null`-ed, but simple `0` will be inlined by javac
    // So `Integer.valueOf(0)` is a kind of cheating to avoid constant inlining
    final int countA = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final List<Person> data = null;

    // Yep, just for debugging purposes
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Response{")
                .append("countA=").append(countA)
                .append(", data=").append(data)
                .append('}')
                .toString();
    }

}
```

```java
final class Person {

    final String name = null;
    final int age = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final int countB = Integer.valueOf(0);
    final List<Course> list = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Person{")
                .append("name='").append(name).append('\'')
                .append(", age=").append(age)
                .append(", countB=").append(countB)
                .append(", list=").append(list)
                .append('}')
                .toString();
    }

}
```

```java
final class Course {

    final String name = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Course{")
                .append("name='").append(name).append('\'')
                .append('}')
                .toString();
    }

}
```

The following demo, where `JSON_1` and `JSON_2` represent your JSON documents

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(List.class, getUnwrappedElementListDeserializer())
            .create();
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson(JSON_1, Response.class));
    System.out.println(gson.fromJson(JSON_2, Response.class));
}
```

will have the following output:

> Response{countA=1, data=[Person{name='peter', age=18, countB=1, list=[Course{name='math'}]}]}
>   Response{countA=2, data=[Person{name='amy', age=17, countB=1, list=[Course{name='music'}]}, Person{name='david', age=16, countB=2, list=[Course{name='music'}, Course{name='computer'}]}]}

Some more comments on your code.

- `Gson` can be instantiated once for many reasons including thread-safety: just put it in a static field (assuming your `fromJson` is `static` as well).
- `gson = null` won't help much - you can just delete this line.
- `fromJson` can be re-implemented very easy: `public static <T> T fromJson(String data, Type type) { return gson.fromJson(data, type); }` - so you  don't need `@SupressWarnings`, you can get rid of type casts at call-site, and, by passing the `Type`, pass *any* type, not just a real type that's the only thing a `Class<T>` instance can hold. Maybe even remove that method for simplicity?
- Registering a type adapter *by Class* binds a (de)serializer for *all* parameterizations. Note that you can bind *concrete* parameterizations with, for example, `.registerTypeAdapter(TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, Course.class).getType(), getUnwrappedElementListDeserializer())` not touching another class parameterizations (this is what `Class<T>` usually can't do). However, even this can affect than you want (say, you want some classes to have such behavior, but not let other classes have this behavior): take a look at the `@JsonAdapter` annotation.
- Consider strings as the last resort to hold JSON documents. In most cases passing a `Reader` instance to the `gson.fromJson()` method is more efficient not requring entire documents to be stored in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is useful and helps me a lot. It solves my question.

Comment: @hochun I'm glad I could help you out, you're welcome!

Comment: Sorry, now I have an other question : Is the thing we call "context.deserialize()" equal to the thing we call default deserializer ? If not, how can I call default deserializer in my own deserializer ?

Comment: @hochun Can you elaborate? What is the default deserializer and why do you need it?

Comment: `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(List.class, getUnwrappedElementListDeserializer())
            .create();` This is the way we create our deserializer. `Gson gson = new Gson();` I think this is the way we create default deserializer. So I curiously want to know that how to call other or default deserializer in our deserializer. Just like nested deserializer. Dose the nested deserializer exist?

Comment: @hochun Of course it does, how would default `Gson` instances work then? Basically you only have (and it's really encouraged) to use the deserialization context -- this is the mechanism you can delegate your type deserialization to. You can, but I would only recommend it as an option of the last resort, pass another `Gson` instance to your deserializer via constructor.

Comment: I think I realize suddenly. You're so nice. Thank you very much.